# How to install the Ceton Infiniti PCIe digital cable tuner card?

Tags: hardware, mythtv, tv-tuner

Can someone give instructions "for dummies" on installing the Ceton Infiniti PCIe digital cable tuner card in Ubuntu 12.04?

Answer (score 1):

I finally got this working, but I didn't (couldn't) use stock Ubuntu.  I'm going to write up what I did, but I'm going to put it as an addendum to the official talk page on MythTV.  You should be able to find it [at the official page](http://www.mythtv.org/wiki/Ceton_InfiniTV_4) when I'm done.

Key Points:

- You need to get and build the drivers from Ceton.  They don't come in Ubuntu 12.04 either as a kernel module or add-on code in apt.  If you update your kernel, you will have to manually re-install the drivers.
- You need to make sure your computer speaks to 192.168.200.1 over the ctn0 interface.  If you have no ctn0 interface, see the above bullet point.
- I couldn't get this to work in MythTV 0.25; I had to use MythBuntu's add-on package to upgrade me to MythTV 0.26.  Then it worked.
- You can't search for channels.  You'll need [SchedulesDirect](http://schedulesdirect.org) in the United States or something similar in your home country to get your appropriate channel list.  If you have a channel list, not searching for channels is perfectly fine.
- You should use mplayer to test your CableCARD setup:

`cat /dev/ceton/ctn91xx_mpeg0_0 | mplayer -cache 8192 -`

Comment: FWIW, I just finished this; the link now has a lot of instructions.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! If possible could you copy the key steps described in the link here so that if the link changes your answer stays valid, thanks in advance!

Comment: Ok, done.  The key "man, I couldn't find these anywhere else on the Internet" points are now added.

Answer (score 0):

Check out http://cetoncorp.com/infinitv_support/linux_drivers/.  Note that Linux support is limited however due to CableCARD rules.